# How do I evaluate this sum(involving the floor function)?

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i}\right\rfloor
$$
Is there a closed form expression to the above sum? (Mathematica doesn't give me anything)

Comment: $N\ln(N)$ would be a good approximation.

Comment: It doesn't have an exact closed form.

Comment: Can you give me a reference?

Comment: @howardh. No, take N = 8, i = 3. $\lfloor \frac{8}{3}\rfloor = 2$

Comment: @Priyatham Right, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721931/finding-the-summation-of-the-floor-of-the-series-identity/

Answer (score 9):

This is Dirichlet's [divisor summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function) $D(x)$. It is known that
$$D(x) = x\log x + x(2\gamma -1) + \Delta(x)$$
and the non-leading term 
$\Delta(x)$ is $O(\sqrt{x})$.
Forget about its closed form, even the behaviour of the non-leading term $\Delta(x)$ is a well known unsolved problem.

> **Dirichlet divisor problem**
>
> Find the smallest value of $\theta$ for which $\Delta(x) = O(x^{\theta+\epsilon})$ holds
>   true for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. In the end I used the $O(\sqrt{x})$ formula for evaluating this sum.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \left \lfloor \frac{N}{i}\right\rfloor \approx \sum_{i=1}^N   \frac{N}{i} = N\sum_{i}^N \frac1{i} = NH_N$$

where $H_n$ is the nth Harmonic number.

For any monotonically decreasing function $f$ we have,

$$\int_1^{n+1}f(x)\,{\rm d}x \le \sum_{i=1}^n f(i) \le 1+\int_1^nf(x)\,{\rm d}x$$

Taking $f(x)=\frac1{x}$, we obtain the well known bound,

$$\ln(n+1)\le H_n\le 1+\ln(n)$$

Thus $H_n \sim \ln(n)$

and our sum is $$S=N\ln(N)$$

**Note:** $H_n=\ln(n) + \gamma$ is a better approximation, where $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni Constant.

---

We can always say that

$$N\ln(N+1) \le S \le N + N\ln(N)$$

Comment: Yes I did. But like told @V.C., I need an exact answer. Also, when you say $n$, do you mean $N$?

Comment: @Priyatham yes I corrected the typo. But till date a closed form hasn't been found.

Comment: Also, since it's a discontinuous function on integers, you can be almost sure that an analytic closed form doesn't exist.

Comment: @Priyatham. There is no hope to arrive to any closed form solution (as already other wrote). The only thing you can hope is to find upper and lower bounds and what Sabyasachi answered is probably almost the best you could get.

Comment: Why is the possibility of a closed form so pessimistically viewed? As far as I understand, Sabyasachi's approximation is already asymptotic to the true value of the function. Now, why does the discontinuity by it self make it "almost sure" that a better, perhaps, exact analytical closed form does not exist - like the gamma function for the factorials?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$  is integer sequence [A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218) in the OEIS. It is equal to a function called the [divisor summatory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function); i.e., it is equal to the sum over the divisor function:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{n}d(k)=D(n).$$