# Finite sum of floor function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose I have the following finite sum;

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right\rfloor}$$
I've never dealt with something like this before and was curious of a way to express it with a closed form.  I can see the first few sums are

$$S_1=1$$
$$S_2=2+1=3$$
$$S_3=3+1+1=5$$
$$S_4=4+2+1+1=8$$
$$S_5=5+2+1+1+1=10$$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740442/how-do-i-evaluate-this-suminvolving-the-floor-function?rq=1).

Comment: Very interesting...

Comment: You can see here 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740442/how-do-i-evaluate-this-suminvolving-the-floor-function

Comment: That's the same link as @sciona's.  Thank you though.