# Floor function solve using any code/tool

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have a function $$ f(n,i)=floor \left(\frac{n}{i} \right)\qquad \text{ for } n,i>0$$

Given any n such that $ 10^{11}< n<10^{12}$, provide a methodology to calculate;
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(n,i)
$$
Solution should involve less than $ 10^7 $operations

You can use any code or excel for the same

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but maybe this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740442/how-do-i-evaluate-this-suminvolving-the-floor-function

Answer (score 0):

let $$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(n,i)$$
Notice that $$f(n,i) = \lfloor\frac{n}{i}\rfloor = Card\{j | j\cdot i\leq n\} $$
So $$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Card\{j | j\cdot i\leq n\} = Card\{(i,j) | j\cdot i\leq n\}$$
The trick is to split this set in two not disjoint parts : 
$$\{(i,j) | j\cdot i\leq n\} = \{(i,j) | j\leq \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor,j\cdot i\leq n\} \cup \{(i,j) | i\leq \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor,j\cdot i\leq n\} $$
Name these sets : $$ S = A \cup B$$
So 
$$F(n) = Card(S) = Card(A\cup B) = Card(A)+Card(B)-Card(A\cap B)$$
A and B are symetrical, so their cardinality is the same, and $Card(A\cap B) = \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2$, So
$$F(n) = 2\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor} \lfloor\frac{n}{i}\rfloor - \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assuming $i$ a continuous variable for a second, note that the slope of $\dfrac ni$ is $-\dfrac n{i^2}$ and its absolute value drops below $1$ when $i\approx\sqrt n$. This means that from $1$ to $\sqrt n$ the ratio $\dfrac ni$ changes by several units every time, and then stays constant longer and longer.

So for $n$ like $10^{12}$, you will compute a sum of $10^6$ varying terms, followed by a sum of roughly $10^6$ constant "runs" of increasing length, for a total of $2\cdot10^6$ operations.