# Closed form of finite sum involving the floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The sum 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p^x-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kx}{p^x} \right\rfloor
$$
has stumped me. I don't even know where I would begin. I suppose that starting with the abstraction
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{f(x)-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kx}{f(x)} \right\rfloor
$$
may help, but I still don't know where to begin. I've looked at [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740442/how-do-i-evaluate-this-suminvolving-the-floor-function), but I still have had no luck solving this problem.

Comment: You can use \left and \right to resize all kinds of brackets, including /lfloor and \rfloor. I went ahead and did that for you, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $p$ or $x$? Mathematica is not giving a closed-form.

Comment: are $x$ and $p$ integers o reals ?

Comment: @G Cab @Math1000 yeah, one can assume that x, p are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x , p^x$ are integral, then you can use the interesting identity
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m - 1} {\left\lfloor {{{nk + x} \over m}} \right\rfloor }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left\lfloor {{{mk + x} \over n}} \right\rfloor }
 \quad \left| \matrix{  \;{\rm integer }m > 0 \hfill \cr 
  \;{\rm integer }n \hfill \cr 
  \;{\rm real }x \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \gcd (m,n)\left\lfloor {{x \over {\gcd (m,n)}}} \right\rfloor  + {{\left( {m - 1} \right)\left( {n - 1} \right)} \over 2} + {{\gcd (m,n) - 1} \over 2} \cr} 
$$

The demonstration is a bit involved, and you can find it in the renowned "Concrete Mathematics" at pag. 94.