# summation of ceil and floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, summation, computational-mathematics

I need a closed solution or a faster algorithm for calculating $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k}-1 \right\rceil $$ 
and $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor $$ where $ n \ge 2$
A step-by-step solution will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help but for the second some there exists an alternative form see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721931/finding-the-summation-of-the-floor-of-the-series-identity?rq=1): $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{n}d(k)$ where $d(k)$ denotes the number of divisors of $k$.

Comment: The second summation I gave is also know as Divisor Summatory Function. [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369) gives a nice proof of that. What I'm worried about is the first problem.

Comment: $\lceil \frac{n}{k}\rceil -\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ is $1$ when $k$ does not divide $n$ and $0$ otherwise. So the difference between the sums is  $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k}-1 \right\rceil - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor = -d(n)$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $k$. Finding a fast solution for one is finding a fast for both

Comment: @Bilou06 am i right in the following comment..?

Comment: You can pull the $-1$ out of the ceiling.

Answer (score 4):

**Observation**

Finding a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$ will be incredibly significant, if it is possible.

It will also mean that a closed form is possible for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$

If you combine these two sums in the following way:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil + n$$
You have a function *f* that counts the number of divisors of n.

Why is this significant? Well, if you put in any positive integer C and the sum equals 2, it means C is prime. Because it has only 2 divisors, 1 and C.

This means that Deterministic Primality Testing can be done in constant time. With the fastest deterministic, unconditional algorithm to date being polynomial is the [AKS Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test).

Even better, lets update our function to:
$$f(C, n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor\frac{C}{k}\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lceil\frac{C}{k}\rceil + n$$

If you plot this function for a given positive integer C, it will have a staircase form with the amount of steps equal to the number of divisors of C.

Because of the staircase form of *f*, it will be possible to output all the divisors of C in approx. log(C) evaluations of *f*, which on our modern day computers is pretty much instant. With the fastest general integer factorization algorithm being the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

Congratulations, we have then solved the [Integer Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) problem.

If these sums do not have closed forms, we still have [Shor's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) that is going to run on upcoming quantum computers that will be able to do Integer Factorization in polynomial time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer.

Comment: @mlc Unless the answer is incorrect, it explains why a closed form solution cannot exist which answers a part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

$\overset{n - 1}{\underset{i = 1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \normalsize = \overset{n}{\underset{i = 1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \normalsize - 1 = D(n) - 1$

You can notice that there is $O(\sqrt{n})$ unique values in the set S = {$\lfloor \frac{n}{1} \rfloor, \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor, \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor, \dots, \lfloor \frac{n}{n - 1} \rfloor, \lfloor \frac{n}{n} \rfloor$}. Therefore you can calculate the function in $O(\sqrt{n})$

Also since this function is asymmetric, you can even calculate x2 faster by using this formula: $D(n) = \overset{u}{\underset{x = 1}{\Large \Sigma}} \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{n}{x} \Large \rfloor \normalsize - u^2$ for $u = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor $

Even more complex but faster: using the method that Richard Sladkey described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369) you can calculate the function in $O(n^{1/3})$

Answer (score 0):

First add results for all k where the result is >= ceil (sqrt (n) + 1), that's about sqrt (n) values. Then for 1 <= m <= ceil (sqrt (n)), find exactly the set of integers k where the result is equal to m, and add m times the number of elements in that set. There are about sqrt (n) calculations for that as well, so a total of 2 x sqrt (n) calculations.

Since ceil (n/k - 1) for example is easier to calculate than the number of integers k for which ceil (n/k - 1) = m, this will be a bit faster if you don't make the switch at sqrt (n) but at some smaller value.

I doubt there is a closed solution, unless you count a sum as a closed solution.

Comment: Can you explain your solution using an example, for convenience let us take n=10. Actually I'm not getting what you want to say.

Comment: Wait a second are you suggesting me to use $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor - {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2 -1$$

Answer (score 0):

@Bilou06 No of pairs of x,y satisfying $ xy \le n $ is given by $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor - {\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}^2 $$
but for $ xy \lt n $ no of pairs is given by $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k} - 1 \right\rceil  $$
or it can be changed into $xy\le n-1 $ and let N = n-1, then no of pairs is given by $$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\left\lfloor \frac{N}{k} \right\rfloor = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{k} \right\rfloor - {\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor}^2 =  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lceil \frac{n}{k} - 1 \right\rceil $$ am I right ??